# How to execute one scenario again and again in cucumber

Tags: cucumber-jvm, scenarios, feature-file

I have a feature file in which there are two scenarios. After first iteration, I want these scenarios to be executed once again.

What do I need to add? Do I need to copy the same java code in the step definition file or is there another method?

Feature File ::

```
@sanity 
Feature: To test Proscape Smoke Test 

Scenario: To launch the Proscape Application Mockup URL 
Given Open the chrome and launch the application 
When user enter url 
And click on Test Project  
And user clicks on Parameter button of Details page
Then Details Page should display  

Scenario Outline: Details page display
Given Details page is diplayed
When user enter value in first Fixture Type "<FF1>"
And user enter second Fixture Type "<FF2>"
And user enter third Fixture Type "<FF3>"
And user clicks on Next button 
Then Category Page should display

Examples:    
| FF1 | FF2 | FF3 |
|  a  | b   | c   |
```

StepDefinition :

```
@Given("^Open the chrome and launch the application$")
    public void open_the_chrome_and_launch_the_application() throws Exception {
        System. setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Mohini\\AutomationStart\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver() ;
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }


@When("^user enter url$")
    public void user_enter_url() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://t53umx.axshare.com/#g=1&p=home");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("landg");
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
        driver.findElement(By.className("loginsubmit")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    }

@When("^click on Test Project$")
    public void click_on_Test_Project() throws Exception {
        driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame"); // use this if it's in frame and you don't know how to locate it
        WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 100)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='u133_img']"))); 

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        action.moveToElement(element).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
        //element.click();
        action.perform();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    }

@When("^user clicks on Parameter button of Details page$")
    public void user_clicks_on_Parameter_button_of_Details_page() throws Exception {
        //driver.findElement(By.id("u47_div")).click();
        try {
            WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long pageLoadTime = (endTime - startTime);
            WebElement element = wdw.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='u47']"))); //we will not use div here in id 

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(5000); 
            element.click();

            System.out.println(pageLoadTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

@Then("^Details Page should display$")
    public void details_Page_should_display() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);     
    }

@Given("^Details page is diplayed$")
    public void details_page_is_diplayed() throws Exception {

    }

@When("^user enter value in first Fixture Type \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_enter_value_in_first_Fixture_Type(String arg1) throws Exception {
        WebDriverWait wdw1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
        WebElement element1 = wdw1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='u68_input']"))); //we will not use div here in id 
        System.out.println("Ff1 = "+arg1);
        element1.sendKeys(arg1);
    }

@When("^user enter second Fixture Type \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_enter_second_Fixture_Type(String arg1) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Ff2 = "+arg1);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u70_input']")).sendKeys(arg1);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

@When("^user enter third Fixture Type \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_enter_third_Fixture_Type(String arg1) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Ff3 = "+arg1);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u71_input']")).sendKeys(arg1);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

@When("^user clicks on Next button$")
    public void user_clicks_on_Next_button() throws Exception {
        Select fixturetype= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u85_input\"]")));
        fixturetype.selectByVisibleText("LED");
        Select lamp= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u84_input\"]")));
        lamp.selectByVisibleText("1000W");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u82_text\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u89_text\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

@Then("^Category Page should display$")
    public void category_Page_should_display() throws Exception {
        //driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
        WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
        WebElement element = wdw.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='u1041']"))); 
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u1197']")).click(); 
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u1117']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u1113\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u1137\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u1215\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u1138\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u1114\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run more Scenario's, you can add them in your feature file.
Using the Scenario Outline with different Examples, it is very easy to add additional test cases.
You can add another example by adding another row in the table, for instance:

```
Examples:    
| FF1 | FF2 | FF3 |
|  a  | b   | c   |
|  d  | e   | f   |
```

From your example, it seems like you want to run the second Scenario (Scenario Outline) from where the first Scenario left off (i.e. once you are on the details page).

If the first scenario is only the setup for the second scenario (or scenario outlines), you should merge them together, like so:

```
@sanity 
Feature: Proscape Smoke Test 

Scenario Outline: Details page display
Given the user opens the details page of the Test Project  
When user enter value in first Fixture Type "<FF1>"
And user enter second Fixture Type "<FF2>"
And user enter third Fixture Type "<FF3>"
And user clicks on Next button 
Then Category Page should display

Examples:    
| FF1 | FF2 | FF3 |
|  a  | b   | c   |
|  d  | e   | f   |
```

Here "Given the user opens the details page of the Test Project" should be implemented as the previous steps (open application url and navigate to details page).